# C# DataTemplate Binding not updating on new isntance of same object type

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I am currently creating custom DataTemplates for some custom lists in a Property grid (RadPropertyGrid from Telerik).

The main issue I keep stumbling upon is my custom bindings defined in the datatemplate not being updated when the parent source is updated.

Given the data structure:

```
    public class SomeDataStruct
    {
            public bool TestBool { get; set; }
            public string TestString { get; set; }
            public Point TestPoint { get; set; }
    }
```

When initially setting the radPropertyGrid item, there is absolutely no issue.

```
    var data1= new SomeDataStruct() { ... };
    radPropertyGrid.Item = data1;
```

All is ok up to this point. Here is where the trouble arises (after having initially set an item of the same data type)

```
    var data2 = new SomeDataStruct() { ... }; //Initialize using completely different variables 
    radPropertyGrid.Item = data2; //Issue occurs here
```

What happens is, **both the boolean and string are properly updated**, however my TestPoint is not being updated. The converter is never being called.

However, if I do this:

```
    radPropertyGrid.Item = null;
    radPropertyGrid.Item = data2;
```

It works completely fine!

Here is my code for creating the DataTemplate to handle the point. Rather simple, it parses the point (0,0, 0 0 etc), and when converting back it returns 0,0.

```
           var fe = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
           fe.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding(path)
            {
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                Converter = new GenericStringConverter<Point>
                    (
                        point => { return (point == null) ? "" : point.ToString(); },
                        str => { return Point.Parse(str);}
                    ),
            });
            dt = new DataTemplate();
            dt.VisualTree = fe;
            dt.DataType = type;
            dt.Seal();
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I could be missing in my datatemplate or binding? I have tried messing with UpdateSourceTrigger and NotifyOnSourceUpdated, but neither seemed to have any effect.

Comment: I've had similar issues, but in an MVVM environment when updating a property in a view model that is bound to a standard WPF control (not Telerik). My workaround has been the same as yours, i.e. set it to null then to the new object. I've never got to the bottom of it and assumed it's just one of those WPF annoyances.